# Why can't Filezilla quick-connect to Sourceforge any more?

Tags: connection, filezilla

I use filezilla so as to access my project's web space at sourceforge.

There is no firewall blocking anything because I can successfully login using the 'sftp' command via a terminal, but I want to use Filezilla, because it is much easier this way to manage your files.

Filezilla used to work fine when I used 11.10, now, when I open Filezilla and fill in the following things:

```
Host: web.sourceforge.net
Username: Username
Password: Password
Port: 21
```

And, when I click on the Quickconnect button on the right I **immediately** get this message:

```
Status: Resolving address of web.sourceforge.net
Status: Connecting to 216.34.181.70:21...
Status: Connection attempt failed with "ECONNREFUSED - Connection refused by server".
Error:  Could not connect to server
Status: Waiting to retry...
```

When  I go to Edit->Network configuration wizard... I am not sure what to do in order to make it work.

I will just mention what are the current settings I have according to what the configuration wizard says when I open it:

**1st page:**

Default transfer mode: Passive

Allow fallback to other transfer mode on failure (ticked)

**2nd page:**

Use the server's external IP address instead

**3rd page:**

Ask your operating system for the external IP address

*Note here: The 3rd option on this page (Get external IP from the following URL) has from default the URL http://ip.filezilla-project.org/ip.php, which, when I open it at my browser, it gives 127.0.0.1 (!) which, obviously, is not correct!*

Don't use external IP address on local connections (ticked)

**4th page:**

Ask operating system for a port.

**5th page:** (Test results are the following:)

```
Connecting to probe.filezilla-project.org
Response: 220 FZ router and firewall tester ready
USER FileZilla
Response: 331 Give any password.
PASS 3.5.3
Response: 230 logged on.
Checking for correct external IP address
IP 192.168.1.254 bjc-bgi-b-cfe
Response: 510 Mismatch. Your IP is 6X.X.XXX.XXX, gc-b-cdi-cdh
Wrong external IP address
Connection closed
```

It is obvious that the local IP address (192.168.1.254) is being sent to sourceforge, which is totally wrong!

Any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*web.sourceforge.net* **does not** support plain FTP (on port 21), only SFTP (i.e. FTP-over-SSH). There really is nothing listening on port 21, hence the ECONNECT error (nothing to do with the external IP).

You need to prefix the URL in QuickConnect with `sftp://`, i.e. `sftp://web.sourceforge.net`, and everything works great:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! That worked perfectly! I didn't need it under 11.10, though, which is weird!

Comment: Perhaps you had a saved profile or something? I don't use Firezilla much, and it has many preferences for fallback, etc. Anyway, glad you got it working! :)

Comment: No, I used the options I specified on my question and it worked like a charm. After I updated to 12.04 a new updated version of filezilla was available, I think, and, when I filled exactly the same things, it didn't work. Weird. Thanks again.